# Java Profiling in Continuous Integration

Tags: java, performance, continuous-integration, profiling, performance-testing

Are there any Java profiling tools that integrate with CI servers like Jenkins?

I've no idea if such things exist, but what would be splendid would be some kind of test framework that yielded results like YourKit Profiler's snapshots. These would be invoked by the CI server, and the results stored along with the build. The result being that one could see a history of performance changes in code units, to aid more holistic performance investigations at a system integration level.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand purpose. CI- is meant for building code, running unit tests and verify that you have a good build. On other hand profiler will inspect CPU, Memory and Threads to give you a look into runtime. While possible - by you writing perf tests and running it as part of build- I would imagine actual user behaviour might be different. Closest I found was : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin

Comment: The purpose would be to identify objective performance for units with each build so that firstly we could look at a historical log of how fast code elements have been, and secondly so that when it comes to running a full-system performance test we would already understand how fast the code runs in isolation, so we can instead focus our attention on things like integration, data and networking.

Comment: @DeejUK Did you find a tool for this?

Comment: I did not, sorry!

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at [spf4j](http://www.spf4j.org), I use it for continuous profiling (profiling always turned on).

It uses sampling for profiling and it can save the profile data to ssdump files, or it can generate html reports. (Spf4j has a UI to visualize the ssdump profile files)