# Monitor Java heap usage in continous integration

Tags: java, performance, build, continuous-integration, performance-testing

I would like to spot bad trends in the memory consumption of my product. I have something in mind like:

1. Execute integration tests in CI environment with activ garbage collection logs
2. Postprocess GC logs after test to find peaks in heap usage (e.g. max heap *after* GC). I would maybe use some Groovy scripts for parsing and doing the statistics.

Record these numbers over time to see if the long-term trend shows surprising changes that need detailled analysis.

Has anyone done something like that before? Is that a completely stupid idea? Is there any advanced tooling?

Comment: It's unlikely that integration tests would represent actual usage patterns of your system, so you wouldn't really be measuring relevant things.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you won't find anything useful from a normal CI test. We are running production-like (well, reasonably) load tests and there gc activity for 24+ hours is quite useful. Some things are visible only after a week or more. You may find some trends in just a few hours, but a typical CI test is probably too short.

If you want to go that route you can of course use the gc logs, but it is much easier to get the data from the JVM, either using Jolokia/JMX or with the jstat tool. Send it to InfluxDB/Graphite/other and graph it with Grafana or something. Being able to compare gc graphs for different periods and correlated with other events reported by the application is great!

Answer (score 0):

[Try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18627585/498976).

There suggest using [spf4j](http://www.spf4j.org/index.html).

I would like to something like launch of microservice to make sure it is able to start with provided memory limits + very fast smoke test.